# SQL query to combine row with aggregate function value based on field content

Tags: sql, postgresql, count

I'm learning SQL and came across a case for which I'm struggling to define the query.

Assume a simple table "tableA", with the following values:

```
col1  
---- 
100 
110 
115 
118 
121 
122
150
```

Now, as a simple example of the type of query I need: for each row, I'd like to count the number of rows for which the value fulfills a certain condition, parameterized by the current field value. So, for example, assuming the condition is "values not larger than the field value + 10", I'd like to create a query that returns the following:

```
col1  counts
------------
100      1    (because only 110 is in the range 100 to 100 + 10)
110      0    (because there are no values in the range 110 to 110 + 10)
121      3    (122, 123, 124 are in the range 121 to 121 + 10)
122      2    (123, 124)
123      1    (124)
124      0
150      ...
```

It's obviously simple to write a query for a given value that returns the counts as

```
select count(*) from tableA where col1 > 100 and col1 < 100 + 11
```

I was considering WITH statements, JOINS, etc. to create the target table above, but no success. Any suggestion how to approach this will be highly appreciated.

PS In case it matters: I am using Postgresql 13

Comment: `count(*) over (order by col1 range between col1 + 1 and col1 + 9)` I can't determine what range you actually want but that's easy to adjust.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT t1.col1,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) - 1 FROM tableA t2 WHERE t2.col1 >= t1.col1 AND t2.col1 <= t1.col1 + 10) counts
FROM tableA t1
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=9aaffc137ef9ed51f9b23450c6393d02).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a self join:

```
select t.col1, count(*) - 1 from tableA t join tableA t1 on t.col1 <= t1.col1 and t1.col1 <= t.col1 + 10 group by t.col1
```